# Is there a way to ignore ViewModel init{} on unit test?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, android-viewmodel

I have a ViewModel with initializer method.

```kotlin
class ExampleViewModel : ViewModel() {
    init {
        println("################init######################")
    }
}
```

In my case, I must ignore this init method on unit tests. How can I do this ?

Comment: If there's no if statement in your init block, it is going to run unconditionally.